# Mongo - Update the database while creating a new entry if necessary

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

What is the best method of updating a row in a Mongo DB from NodeJS (preferably with Mongoose) while row if it does not already exist, create it. I've tried multiple functions, `save` `findOneAndUpdate` `update`. They are all dependant on one another, the row has to exist to be able to update it, for instance.

How can we combine these features into a function:

```
If the entry does not exist by 'name', create it, and then...
If the entry does exist, update 'password' with 'data'
```

Assuming a mongo collection that could look like:

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("5357c8e0b12b6c375bb0217b"),
"name": "Kimberly",
"password": "data"
}
```

My current code is a mess with a lot of if statements and relying on `err` responses to call database functions. (Check if a user exists before adding them, for example) Is there a better way to make sure there are no duplicate entries in the database after updating or saving something?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

you may use findAndModify with upsert=true

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/